# Swift: FileManager().fileExists(atPath: (fileURL.path)) without knowing extension

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

)

today I have a problem and I can't find an easy solution.

With:

```
FileManager().fileExists(atPath:(fileURL.path))
```

it's simple to find out if a file exist. Actually I have the file name but don't know the extension. How can I use FileManager() to find a file without the extension. Something like .deletingPathExtension() for FileManger().fileExists?
Something like

```
ls filename.*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a FileManager extension that retrieves the contents of the directory and filters for files as well as the expected filename.

It might look something like this:

```
extension FileManager {
    func urls(of filename: String, in directory: URL)  -> [URL]? {
        guard let urls = try? contentsOfDirectory(at: directory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            else { return nil }
        
        return urls.filter { url in
            !url.hasDirectoryPath && url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent == filename
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, one would call it something like this:

```
let directory = URL(string: "file:///Users/stephan/tmp")!
if let urls = FileManager.default.urls(of: "test", in: directory) {
    for url in urls {
        print("do something with url: \(url)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you for your answer. I hoped there would be a solution without filtering the whole directory.  But that helps me a lot!